# Why am i getting False in this boolean question

Tags: python, boolean

```
A= True

B= True

y = not(A or B) == (not(A)) and (not(B))

print (y)
```

gives output as False on python.

Should it not be true (False==False)?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Answer (score 1):

You need to pay attention to order of operations.

In general, it is always preferred to use parenthesis when it is ambiguous.

In your case, it is translated as

```
A = True
B = True
y = (not(A or B) == (not(A))) and (not(B))
```

which if we follow carefully is:

```
y = (not(True or True) == (not(True))) and (not(True))
y = (not(True) == (False)) and (False)
y = (False == False) and (False)
y = True and False
y = False
```

Hope this helps, and good luck on your journey

Answer (score 0):

this what you need to do to get what you wanted :
y =  not(A or B) == ( not(A) and not(B) )

in what you did you got not(A or B) == (not(A)) as true and after this you have
true and (not(B)) and this false!